# How to show the function is surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} : x+y\neq -1\}$ Define $f : A\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ by

$f(x, y) = (\frac{y}{1+x+y}, \frac{x}{1+x+y})$ Then $f(A)=\mathbb{R^2}$. Is it true?, I try to show the function is surjective, but i did not reach the final conclusion. please help me to give the details solution.

Comment: Have you tried to fix an arbitrary $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and solve the system of equations $f(x,y)=(a,b)$ to see if there exist preimages $(x,y)\in A$?

Comment: @ClementC. i get $x=\frac{a}{1-a-b}$ and $y=\frac{b}{1-a-b}$, from it may i say $f(A)= \mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: If for any point $(a,b)$ there is (at least) a preimage by $f$ (in the domain $A$ of $f$), then $f$ is surjective on $\mathbb{R}^2$. That's the definition of surjectivity.